# Why does the docker-compose healthcheck of my mongo container always fail?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose` to stand up an Express/React/Mongo app.  I can currently stand up everything using retry logic in the express app.  However, I would prefer to use Docker's [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) to prevent the string of errors when the containers initially spin up.  However, when I add a `healthcheck` in my `docker-compose.yml`, it hangs for the interval/retry time limit and exits with:

```
ERROR: for collector  Container "70e7aae49c64" is unhealthy.

ERROR: for server  Container "70e7aae49c64" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

It seems that my healthcheck never returns a healthy status, and I'm not entirely sure why.  The entirety of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodb/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo mongo:27017/test --quiet 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  collector:
    build: ./collector/
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./collector/:/app
    depends_on:
      mongo:
        condition: service_healthy
  server:
    build: .
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=$SERVER_PORT
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/app
    ports:
      - "${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}"
    depends_on:
      mongo:
        condition: service_healthy
```

For the `test`, I've also tried:

```
["CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "27017"]
```

And:

```
["CMD", "bash", "/mongo-healthcheck"]
```

I've also tried ditching the `healthcheck` altogether, following the advice of [this guy](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/issues/139#issuecomment-305964226).  Everything stands up, but I get the dreaded errors in the output before a successful connection:

```
collector_1  | MongoDB connection error: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect 
ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.2:27017]
collector_1  | MongoDB connection with retry
collector_1  | MongoDB connection error: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect
```

The ultimate goal is a clean startup output when running the `docker-compose up --build`.  I've also looked into some of the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y/41854997#41854997), but I haven't had much luck with `wait-for-it` either.  What's the correct way to wait for Mongo to be up and running before starting the other containers, and achieving a clean startup?

Answer (score 31):

[The mongo shell is removed from MongoDB 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/#the-mdb-shell-versus-the-legacy-mongo-shell). The replacement is mongosh.

Check if this works for you :

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongosh localhost:27017/test --quiet
```

Answer (score 26):

Firstly, I'd suggest to update the docker-compose.yaml file version to at least 3.4 (`version: "3.5"`), then please add the `start_period` option to your mongo `healthcheck`

> Note: start_period is only supported for v3.4 and higher of the compose file format.
>
> start period provides initialization time for containers that need time to bootstrap. Probe failure during that period will not be counted towards the maximum number of retries. However, if a health check succeeds during the start period, the container is considered started and all consecutive failures will be counted towards the maximum number of retries.

So it would look something like this:

```
healthcheck:
  test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo mongo:27017/test --quiet
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 5
  start_period: 40s
```

Comment: I'd prefer a newer version, but [version 3 looses the `condition` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on).  Will that make a difference?  Making the changes now, I'll keep you posted :)

Comment: +1 for learning something new, but that still leaves the startup with `MongoDB connection error`s from the retry logic in the Express app.  Thanks for looking into it, though, and if you have any other ideas I'm open to them!

Comment: Try: `depends_on: ["mongo"]`

Answer (score 11):

We can use MongoDB's [serverStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/) command to do the health check, as the MongoDB document puts it this way:

> Monitoring applications can run this command at a regular interval to collect statistics about the instance.

Because this command `serverStatus` requires authentication, you need setup the health check similar to the configuration shown below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand({serverStatus:1}).ok' | mongo admin -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --quiet | grep 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 20s
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

That's it. If your MongoDB instance is healthy, you will see something similar to mine:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND                 CREATED         STATUS                   PORTS      NAMES
01ed0e02aa70  mongo  "docker-entrypoint.s…"  11 minutes ago  Up 11 minutes (healthy)  27017/tcp  demo_mongo_1
```

Comment: Great answer! However, the command "mongo" should be replaced with "mongosh".

Answer (score 11):

Note that you probably should use mongosh if you use newer versions of mongodb:

```
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD","mongosh", "--eval", "db.adminCommand('ping')"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 5s
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here
https://github.com/docker-library/healthcheck/tree/master/mongo

Note, it explains why health check is not included into official image
https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/pull/76#issuecomment-246054271

**docker-healthcheck**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

if mongo --quiet "localhost/test" --eval 'quit(db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2)'; then
    exit 0
fi

exit 1
```

In the example from the link, they use **host** variable

```
host="$(hostname --ip-address || echo '127.0.0.1')"

if mongo --quiet "$host/test" --eval 'quit(db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2)'; then
# continues the same code
```

It did not work for me, so I replaced the **host** with **localhost**.

In **docker-compose**

```
mongo:
  build:
    context: "./mongodb"
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: crm-mongo
  restart: always
  healthcheck:
    test:  ["CMD", "docker-healthcheck"]
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 2s
    retries: 10
```

Alternatively, you can execute health checks in container. Change **Dockerfile** or that.

```
FROM mongo:4

ADD docker-healthcheck /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Some quick action tips:

1 - Use mongosh and use double dollar when calling environment variables:

```
test: echo 'db.runCommand({serverStatus:1}).ok' | mongosh admin -u $$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --quiet | grep 1
```

2 - Quick check service health with docker inspect:

```
sudo docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" mongo | jq
```

3 - If not "healthy", go inside docker and test:

```
sudo docker exec -it <container_id> bash
root@container_id:/# echo 'db.runCommand({serverStatus:1}).ok' | mongosh admin -u <MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME> -p <MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD> --quiet | grep 1
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

When i execute the `echo db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo localhost:27017/test --quiet 1` command in the docker container, the result is:

```
    2019-04-19T02:39:19.770+0000 E -        [main] file [1] doesn't exist
    failed to load: 1
```

Try this

```
healthcheck:
  test: bash -c "if mongo --eval 'quit(db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2)'; then exit 0; fi; exit 1;"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD","mongo", "--eval", "db.adminCommand('ping')"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 5
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).