# docker-compose mongo healthcheck failing

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Hello my mongo health check is failing
below is my docker-compose file

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  production-api:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/productiondb
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
        - mongodb   
        # condition: service_healthy

  mongodb:

    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    # healthcheck:
    #   test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo mongo:27017/productiondb --quiet 1
    #   interval: 10s
    #   timeout: 10s
    #   retries: 5
```

And is there any way to pass MONGO_URI to health check as a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're healthcheck should look like this:

```
test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo localhost:27017/productiondb --quiet
```

- the hostname `mongo` doesn't exist inside the `mongodb` container unless you specify `hostname: mongo` in your compose file or just simply use `localhost` which is more common, when doing healthchecks
- the `1` after `--quiet` seems to be a typo which leads to `[main] file [1] doesn't exist` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-quiet

see also:

- [Simple HTTP/TCP health check for MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839365/simple-http-tcp-health-check-for-mongodb)
- [Why does the docker-compose healthcheck of my mongo container always fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384042/why-does-the-docker-compose-healthcheck-of-my-mongo-container-always-fail)

You can pass `MONGO_URI` to the healthcheck, by specifying it a second time:

```
mongodb:
..
environment:
- MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/productiondb
```

If you want to use one value for both, create an `env_file` and use it via:

```
env_file:
- mongo.env  # wich contains `MONGO_URI=mongodb://..`
```

Comment: If you are reading this in 2023 or 2024, use `mongosh` instead of `mongo` in the healthcheck.test:

`test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongosh localhost:27017/productiondb --quiet`