# Docker health check always fails for mongodb and cassandra

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, cassandra

I've been trying to start a mongoDB and cassandra container and make them pass two simple health checks, but they keep failing no matter what health check I put:

For mongoDB, here's my yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mongo --quiet 127.0.0.1/test --eval 'quit(db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2)'"]
      start_period: 5s
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 120s
      retries: 24
```

and for cassandra:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/cassandra:3-debian-10'
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '9042:9042'
    volumes:
      - 'cassandra_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1G
      - HEAP_NEWSIZE=800M
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "cqlsh --username cassandra --password ${CASSANDRA_PASSWORD} -e 'describe cluster'" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 120s
      retries: 24
```

Am I missing something,

I also tried running this for the health check:

````
echo 'db.runCommand({serverStatus:1}).ok' | mongo admin -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --quiet | g$$et | grep 1```
I went trough a lot of the discussions about the healthchecks for mongo and cassandra, but still not able to make it work
````

Answer (score 4):

For everyone still out there trying to figure out how to set the health check for mongo container, use this

```
healthcheck:
  test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongosh localhost:27017/productiondb --quiet
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
  start_period: 20s
```

The reason why (at least for me) it was not working before is because I was using mongo instead of mongosh while the recent versions of mongo uses the newer mongosh shell

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same problem, I found my answer here for cassandra:

https://quantonganh.com/2021/09/09/docker-compose-healthcheck

```yaml
    healthcheck:
      test: cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -k <YOUR_KEYSPACE_NAME>
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you shoudn't use CMD-SHEEl but CMD:
[Related github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/28679)

Can you share healthcheck status and any log that can be useful to help you ?

I think this thread can help you: [Why does the docker-compose healthcheck of my mongo container always fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384042/why-does-the-docker-compose-healthcheck-of-my-mongo-container-always-fail)

Sincerly,